# How to pass props from child to parent?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and this is the tic tac toe game, i have to pass props from child to parent in this case. I want to get each box value to board component and do some algorithm.

Here is my parent component;

```
import React from "react";
import Square from "./Square"

export default function Board() {
    return (
        <div className="game-board">
            <Square key="1" />
            <Square key="2" />
            <Square key="3" />
            <Square key="4" />
            <Square key="5" />
            <Square key="6" />
            <Square key="7" />
            <Square key="8" />
            <Square key="9" />
        </div>
```

Here is my child component;

```
import React from "react";

export default function Square() {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState()
    const [mutate, setMutate] = React.useState(false)

    function handleClick() {
        !mutate && setMutate(true)
    }
    return (
        <div className="square" onClick={handleClick}>{value}</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties should not be passed upward. That's a violation of fundamental application principles. Instead, pass a function *down* which updates the state. See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up).

Parent:

```
const doSomeWork = () { // update app state } 

<Square key="1" onSomeAction={doSomeWork} />
```

Child:

```
onClickOrWhatever={props.onSomeAction}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [useimperativehandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) hook to expose values from child to parent.

Comment: You _can_, but you shouldn't.